# Speech Recognition Api for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, speech-recognition

Is there any API available for Blackberry OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iSpeech has a TTS and Speech Recognition API available:

[speech recognition](http://www.ispeech.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and found two possibilities:

- MyCaption API (http://www.mycaption.com/resources/api)
- Yap, HTTP-based (http://yapinc.com/speech-cloud.html)

Comment: But these all are paid and i doint want the server side process

Comment: Please specify those details in your question next time!